# Terrible performance with the MongoDB native Node.js driver compared to Mongoose, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple `node/express` app that needs to get the 2 documents stored inside a sample MongoDB collection `(32-bit, localhost, Windows)`. I could use either the `native driver` or `Mongoose ORM`.

Going with the native driver tore my app apart. Did an ApacheBench (3300 requests, 5 at a time) and the whole thing timed out...

```
Completed 330 requests
apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
```

The same MongoDB collection when accessed through Mongoose simply flies through the task by comparison...

```
...
Completed 2970 requests
Completed 3300 requests
Finished 3300 requests
...
Requests per second:    244.49 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       61.353 [ms] (mean)
```

That is a *massive* difference and obviously I'm doing something terribly wrong when using the native driver. Here's the code for both the approaches along with the data stored in the DB.

**Only two documents stored in the DB:**

```
{
    "_id": "51bmdft4a487e771411ce8ef",
    "name": "Gintoki",
    "email": "sakata@yorozuya.com",
    "friends": [ "Shinpachi", "Kagura", "Tsukuyo" ]
},
{
    "_id": "51388p50bed4dghy4308745d",
    "name": "Elizabeth",
    "email": "eli@ossan.io",
    "friends": [ "Katsura" ]
}
```

**Using the Native MongoDB driver:**

```
var 
    app         = require( 'express' )(),
    MongoClient = require( 'mongodb' ).MongoClient,
    DB_URL      = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB';

app.get( '/mongotest', function ( req, res ) {

    MongoClient.connect( DB_URL, function ( err, db ) {
        if( !err ) {
            var collection = db.collection( 'People' );
            collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
                res.send( JSON.stringify( items ) );
            })
        }
    })
})

app.listen( 5000 );
```

**Output**: Timed out afer a minute completing only 330 of the 3300 requests made by `ab`

---

**Using Mongoose:**

```
var 
    app         = require( 'express' )(),
    mongoose    = require( 'mongoose' ),
    DB_URL      = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB';

app.get( '/mongotest', function ( req, res ) {

    mongoose.connect( DB_URL );

    var 
        PeopleSchema = mongoose.Schema({ name: String, email: String, friends: Array }),
        People = mongoose.model( 'People', PeopleSchema ),
        db = mongoose.connection;

    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
    db.once('open', function callback () {
        People.find({}, function ( err, item ) {
            res.send( item );
        })
    })
})

app.listen( 5000 );
```

**Output**: Blazing fast compared to the native driver. `ab` done in a few seconds.

Anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong with the native driver?

Comment: Have you tried switching from using `toArray` to using `stream`? http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html#time-to-query

Comment: right - .toArray() forces a get of the full contents of the collection  - to convert them to a local array.  You are not doing that in mongoose, you don't want to be doing it in native driver.

Comment: Actually Mongoose's `find` does convert the full results to an array, so that's comparable (besides, it's only two docs).  Pretty sure the problem here is that in the native version a new connection pool is opened on each request.  Rework your code so that the `MongoClient.connect` and the `mongoose.connect` calls are only made once, during startup.

Comment: @JohnnyHK I thought so myself; creating a new DB conn per request was the problem but in Mongoose the connection is established inside the routes and I assumed the native driver worked the same way. I'm taking the DB conn out of the routes now, will post results soon.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yep, that was it. Took the DB conn outside the routes and it bested Mongoose's 245 requests/s by almost two times: 451 r/s. Can you post your comment as an `answer` so I can accept it?

Comment: @vjk2005 Any chance you could post (or link to a gist of) how you reworked your native driver code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pretty sure the problem is that in the native version a new connection pool is opened on each request. Rework your code so that the `MongoClient.connect` and the `mongoose.connect` calls are only made once, during startup